# Dynamically change column name in R/Tidyverse dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am refactoring the following block of code:

```
my_function(dataframe, "GroupA", 25) %>% 
  arrange(desc(percent)) %>% 
  rename(percent_A=percent)

my_function(dataframe, "GroupB", 50) %>% 
  arrange(desc(percent))%>% 
  rename(percent_B=percent)

my_function(dataframe, "GroupC", 75) %>% 
  arrange(desc(percent))%>% 
  rename(percent_C=percent)

my_function(dataframe, "GroupD",100) %>% 
  arrange(desc(percent))%>% 
  rename(percent_D=percent)

# ...
```

As the first step, I would like to use an imperative approach. Therefore I defined a matrix and tried to write a loop, however I'm struggling with dynamically renaming the column:

```
params = 
+----------+-----+
| "GroupA" |  25 |
| "GroupB" |  50 |
| "GroupC" |  75 |
| "GroupD" | 100 |
| ...      | ... |
|----------+-----+

for(i in 1:nrow(params)) {
    my_function(dataframe, params[i,1], params[i,2]) %>% 
        arrange(desc(percent)) %>% 
        rename(percent_D=percent)
#                      ^------- here
}
```

What should I use to accomplish something like: `rename("percent" + substring(params[i, 1], 5, 1) = percent)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(params)) {
  my_function(dataframe, params[i,1], params[i,2]) %>% 
    arrange(desc(percent)) %>% 
    rename(!!paste0("percent", substring(params[i, 1], 6, 6)) := percent)
}
```

`!!` evaluates the expression and returns the new name, `:=` is required because you don't directly provide a string or symbol on the LHS but an expression.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately I wasn't able to check it yet, I'll let you know once I manage to verify